# Is there a way to create a django model foreignkey field with variable choices?

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have three models **device**, **mechanical** and **digital**. In the device model I have a field **type**. The **type** field needs to be in a foreign key relationship with either **mechanical** or **digital** model which will be determined by the data. Is there any way to create the **type** field in such a way that the model in which the foreign key relationship is to be done can be chosen manually.
Something like:
type = models.ForeignKey(to=Choices)
where the Choices could be digital and mechanical.

I have tried implementing generic foreign keys but my database schema is a bit complex so that would be very difficult to maintain. Is there any other way in django that I can do the above?

Comment: I am not aware of this possibility. It defeats a bit the purpose of a database. You usually or want to restrict the options to a predefined set, defined in the code, or you want to restrict the options to a runtime set, stored in a database, referred to by ForeignKey. The combination is rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way that you can manage this would be to use your own models.

Create a ChoiceItemGroup model, slug, name, description.

Create another model ChoiceItem, with slug, name, description, and FK to ChoiceItemGroup.

Then you can do:

```
type=models.ForeignKey(ChoiceItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then you can create generic choices and generic choice groups by registering the models in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

Adding a foreign key from one of your own models to ContentType allows your model to effectively tie itself to another model class, But it’s possible to go one step further and use ContentType to enable truly generic (sometimes called “polymorphic”) relationships between models.

For example, it could be used for a tagging system like so:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

[Django generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)